# Are p-type and n-type regions charged?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I've read that once the p-n junction is formed, the electrons from the n-region diffuse to the p-region, creating negative ions in the p-region ([source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/pnjun.html))

Does this mean that the p and n-regions are not charged before the p-n junction is created?

If so, why isn't the n-region negative from the excess electrons and the p-region positive from the electron holes?

If not, what causes electrons from the n-region to go over to the holes in the p-region? Is it just the repulsive force from the other electrons?

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that the p and n-regions are not charged before the p-n junction is created?

Yes.  The bulk material will be electrically neutral.

> If so, why isn't the n-region negative from the excess electrons and the p-region positive from the electron holes?

Because the [dopant](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/dope.html#c3) (that creates the n-region) is a different element, and contains a different number of protons (positive charges) from the base semiconductor.  The bulk n-type material has an excess of electrons, but also an excess of protons.

While it is electrically neutral, the electrons do not have identical energy levels, so migration takes place when the junction is created.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should understand is what p type semiconductors are and what n type semiconductors are.
Both these types are ***electrically neutral*** since no ionization or anything like that takes place.
Now when we consider a diode,you must now understand that it is electrically neutral.What essentially happens in the p-n junction when electrons from the n type region move to the p type region is that a depletion zone is created .
In order to get a better insight about this depletion zone this link will help you.[Depletion region-Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion_region)

Answer (score 0):

Both p-type and n-type semiconductors will be electrically neutral in their "normal" form. This is because in each semiconductor the number of protons and electrons are equal.

Note that a n-type semiconductor does have an excess of free electrons due to pentavalent atoms **but the atom also contributes an extra proton thus making it overall electrically neutral**. The names p and n do not refer to the charge on the semiconductor but refer to the **polarity of the majority charge carriers**.

> If not, what causes electrons from the n-region to go over to the holes in the p-region? Is it just the repulsive force from the other electrons?

When the two are joined in a p-n junction diode there is a concentration difference between both charge carriers on either side. The trivalent atoms on the p-side will accept electrons to complete their octet (becoming negatively charged in the process) and electrons will migrate from the n-side where they are more available to the p-side as a result (making the pentavalent atoms positively charged).